Is the law of self-preservation a Divine law in Hobbes's view?
I am currently reading about Spinoza's notion of Divine Law in the Tractatus Theologico-Politicus and its relation to Hobbes' account of the ‘Fundamental Law of Nature' in De Cive II. While I have a clear understanding of Spinoza’s views, I am uncertain about Hobbes'.
Specifically, I’m trying to clarify whether Hobbes considers the natural law of self-preservation to be Divine Law or as put in the English edition of De Cive edited by Howard Warrender, which states that

'The natural and moral law is divine... which is confirmed in Scripture in general, especially regarding the fundamental law of nature in seeking peace'.

Does Hobbes view the natural law of self-preservation as Divine Law? Or is the Divine Law here dictated by scriptures in terms of seeking peace (for example, the Ten Commandments)?
Or is it both to some extent?

On some accounts, it is not, it is not even a law of nature, see Martinich, Law and Self-Preservation in Leviathan:"Contrary to the view of his contemporaries, self-preservation is a desire, a physiological condition, not a law or command. The concept of self-preservation is an important part of the definition of “law of nature.” But the definition is no more a law of nature than the definition of an elephant is an elephant. The content of the laws of nature are deduced from the definition of “a law of nature.”"

The problem is that Hobbes is none too clear in what he says about natural law and God's commands and many commentators suspect him of insincerity in what he does say, see Forster for a review:"There is a fatal interpretive flaw in the 'sincere' reading — no argument can be made consistent with Hobbes's philosophy to show that the natural law of self-preservation is in fact God's law, so his natural-law doctrine cannot rely on God's moral authority as Hobbes claims it does."

From my understanding, it is both because reason (a tool given by god) leads human to discover these laws. So both Divine, Natural Law (and the scripture) are intertwined.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
